# How to deserialize a json data using GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, illegalstateexception, gson

```
    [{"contacts": 
     [
        {
            "name": "Ramesh Sippi",
            "email": "ramesh.sippi@gmail.com",
            "phone": 9972366543,
            "officePhone": 80012345676,
            "latitude": 18.5204,
            "longitude": 73.8567
        }
    ]
}]
```

I tried to deserialize above JSON but it shows :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object
```

Deserializer class is:

```
public class Deserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<ContactDetails>> {
@Override
public List<ContactDetails> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    String CONTACTS = "contacts";
    return new Gson().fromJson(json.getAsJsonArray().getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray(CONTACTS),typeOfT);
}}
```

Please help me out.Any resource or tutorial which helped you in deserialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.getAsJsonArray().getAsJsonObject()` is the same as `json.getAsJsonObject()`, and that is the cause of your exception.

You likely meant `json.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject()`.

Comment: plz help me with dis josn  **data:[{key:value},null,{key:value}]**

Comment: @Manish If you have a question, you should ask a question (click the "Ask Question" link in upper right corner), not piggyback on an answer to the question of someone else.

Comment: sry but i just want a suggestion that how i parsw that json

Comment: @Andreas I tried this: json.getAsJsonObject().get(CONTACTS).getAsJsonArray(); but still the error occurs.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Of course, because the element in `json` is **not** a `JsonObject`, so `json.getAsJsonObject()` throws exception. Read my answer again, and try what I suggested, i.e. add `get(0)` between `getAsJsonArray()` and `getAsJsonObject()`.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much. I did what you have suggested: json.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get(CONTACTS).getAsJsonArray() & It now deserializes JSON data.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have your json inside [], which would indicate an array. Try:

```
{
    "contacts": 
     [
        {
            "name": "Ramesh Sippi",
            "email": "ramesh.sippi@gmail.com",
            "phone": 9972366543,
            "officePhone": 80012345676,
            "latitude": 18.5204,
            "longitude": 73.8567
        }
    ]
}
```